# Terminate default EC2 t1.micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am new with AWS EC2. I see that after following the [Setting Up Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html) I have a running default instance t1.micro without key-pair associated.

I have launched a new t2.micro instance with a key-pair associated and it is running properly, but I want to remove the t1.micro one. When I click on Terminate it shuts down, but after one minute a new t1.micro instance is running again.

What can I do in order to keep just my t2.micro instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's genuinely a new instance, you likely have an autoscaling group and launch configuration set up. Check those sections of the console.

If it's the same instance ID, your termination command is failing for some reason. If no error is being shown in the console, contact AWS Support.